# Problems exporting a functional component in a ReactJS Module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, node-modules

I'm having problems importing my functional component `BusinessCard` (declared here https://github.com/HenryFBP/react-business-card-hfbp/blob/master/src/BusinessCard.tsx#L20)

into a different project (here https://github.com/HenryFBP/personal-website-react/blob/master/src/pages/PageContact.tsx#L3).

I used `npm link react-business-card-hfbp`, and I can see the symlinked folder, but I must be doing the export incorrectly or don't understand `package.json`.

I have also tried installing from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-business-card-hfbp/ but that does not seem to work either.

The error (below) from webpack is `Module '"react-business-card-hfbp"' has no exported member 'BusinessCard'.`. I tried so many different combinations, edited `package.json` quite a lot, but I am stuck on this.

[image: z]

I'm sure the answer is simple, I just don't have enough experience with Node Modules to understand what is going on.

Thanks so much <3

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! With the help of a kind person on "Reactiflux" Discord server.

TL;DR: I was not compiling it into a module correctly. I should have used `parcel` to compile it into a module. I thought that TypeScript could be included in modules - this is apparently not correct, you must somehow turn it all into JavaScript first.

Working code:

```
npm run build
npm publish
```

Working `package.json`:

https://github.com/HenryFBP/react-business-card-hfbp/blob/master/package.json#L42